# Jive does not sync avatar with Active Directory

Tags: rest, active-directory, jive

Currently our active directory is synced up with the jive platform, however the avatar on jive does not sync across to active directory, but everything else does.  I was wondering if it is possible to make them sync using the JIVE REST API?  If there are any other details that are needed I can provide this

Comment: Though I don't know the answer, I know another good place to ask if you don't get an answer here: https://community.jivesoftware.com/community/support/jive

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to set the user avatar via the API in Jive. Please check the API documentation for this [method](https://developers.jivesoftware.com/api/v3/cloud/rest/PersonService.html#setAvatar(String,%20String,%20MultipartBody)).

However, if there is an issue with the AD sync you should first attempt to solve this to avoid this additional implementation.